# Hybrid Connections in Azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, hybrid-cloud

I have created a sample ASP.NET MVC app (the standard one you get in Visual Studio). I have deployed this to Azure and it works fine. I have SQL Server 2016 running locally (on premise) on my machine and the cloud app uses this database. I have created a hybrid connection and everything is connected as it should be. But when I run the app its not connecting to the database for some reason. The connection string works fine locally:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=MyPC-QQ5, 1433;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=sa;Password=thePassword!;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is anyone else experiencing this problem.

Comment: Did you install the Hybrid Connection Manager? What's the connection status (both Azure Portal and HCM UI)?

Comment: yes, both are connected status

Comment: Are you sure your database listens on your network interface as well? The HCM will source packets from whatever your private IP is, NOT 127.0.0.1. It will also not use named pipes.

Comment: how do i check this?

Comment: `netstat -an | findstr 1433` and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: done all this - still getting the error

Comment: You should post the error + stack trace.

Comment: this is the error im getting: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Comment: Can you try tcpping your sql server from your app service (go to advanced tools in azure portal -> debug console -> cmd) and see if you get a response?

Comment: That's a bad test. `tcpping` will always succeed since you are pinging the Service Bus relay endpoint (remember Hybrid Connections is the glue between two TCP pipes, `WebApp->HybridConnEndpoint(SB Relay) and onpremHCM->HybridConnEndpoint(SB Relay)`. `sqlcmd.exe` would make for a relevant test. Use it, it's bundled with Kudu.